# Two problems; My website is adding to it's size for no reason/My image links aren't appearing

Tags: html, css, image, size, hyperlink

My website is bigger than it should, the scrollbars shouldn't appear, it's like their an object there, but there isn't. And the links at the footer aren't working. Only one of them are, it seems like each of them are overlapping or something.
http://justxp.x10.mx/test/

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please post one only issue at a time in your questions. It makes it easier to focus on the problem. Also it is extremely helpful if you post the particular code that you are having issues with so we dont have to search your entire site.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You need to be more specific, I'm afraid. What does "bigger than it should" mean? Did you do a "view source" on the page to see what's actually there? It's not particularly nice to ask people for free help, and then expect them to do a lot of work to figure out what it is you're actually asking. Being clear with your question, and providing details, makes it much more likely someone can help you. :-)

Comment: Posting the code is important.
Linking to the website that you are going to fix,
means that is is much harder for anyone else to understand the question in the future.
Stack overflow is like a reference book - the ultimate (F)AQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the `left:111px` in `#footerhighscores`   and  in `#footerstore` remove the  `left: 333px;`

and add   `margin: 0 auto;` in  `#footerstore`

you have set the position according the width of your screen **don't do this** try to make the center floated layout

in your website there is major designing issues you haven't set the position correct there are lots of issue on your `footer` and `front` divs try to use the [firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) and  [Mozilla web developer  tool](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/web-developer/)